# Using bookmark to open a file but always in a given position

Tags: emacs, elisp, bookmarks

When using bookmarks to open a file, is there a way to always open at a particular position of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs default behavior when bookmarking with `C-x r m` is to bookmark the file AND the position.  So, if you use that command (bookmark-set) it will have the behavior you're asking for.

If you `C-h k C-x r m` to view the documentation:

> C-x r m runs the command bookmark-set,
>   which is an interactive compiled Lisp
>   function in `bookmark.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x r m, 
>     .
>
> (bookmark-set &optional NAME
>   NO-OVERWRITE)
>
> Set a bookmark named NAME at the
>   current location.

Answer (score 1):

It can even set two positions (the region), if you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus).